# How to display some static text by clicking button text should disappear using ionic 2?

Tags: html, angular, ionic2

I am new to ionic 2,In front of ion-icon i want some text in the same row which means by in default there is div tag,in div tag there is text, by clicking the remove icon the text should disappear.
Below is my code:

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item no-lines (click)="toggleLanguages()" class="content">
      <ion-icon name="create" item-left class="sai"></ion-icon>     
       Language 
       <div class="english">English 
       <ion-icon name="add" item-right *ngIf="languageShow" ></ion-icon>
       <ion-icon name="remove" item-right *ngIf="languageHide"></ion-icon>
     </div>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list
```

Comment: Am I right if i say that you want the "Languages" to disappear when your dropdown expands and "English" to show? And when the dropdown closes that "English" disappears and "Languages" shows?

Comment: Because basically you start off on `languageShow = false` (if I correctly remember your code). Then you can just put a `<span *ngIf="languageShow">English</span>` for example

Comment: @ Ivaro18 no,i want english to appear as default language and when i click the remove button english should disappear.

Comment: Okay then the second comment will work. `languageShow` is default `false` and will only be set to `true` when the remove icon is clicked. (at least if you're still using the same `toggleLanguages()`)

Comment: yes,i am using toogleLanguages()

Comment: @ Ivaro tq bro i had got exact output what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <ion-list>
    <ion-item no-lines (click)="toggleLanguages()" class="content">
      <ion-icon name="create" item-left class="sai"></ion-icon>     
       Language 
       <div class="english">
         <span *ngIf="languageHide">English</span> 
         <ion-icon name="add" item-right *ngIf="languageShow" ></ion-icon>
         <ion-icon name="remove" item-right *ngIf="languageHide"></ion-icon>
     </div>
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

IF your TS looks like this (for example)

```
public languageShow: boolean = false;
public languageHide: boolean = true;

toggleLanguages() {
    this.languageShow = !this.languageShow;
    this.languageHide = !this.languageHide;
}
```

When 'remove' is pressed, `languageHide` turns `false`, thus, returning in the `<span>` where "English" is printed not being shown.

Then if the 'add' is pressed, you will see your "English" again (or any other language name you configured)